# Android emulator not launching Xamarin app

Tags: macos, android-emulator, xamarin.android, xamarin

I am trying to run Xamarin's Tasky app in the Android emulator from Xamarin Studio on my mac.  The emulator launches, but the app does not.  I always see one of the two screens below.  How can I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting the emulator takes time. Once it's running, don't stop it, your next debug session will start faster.

To solve your issue, when you're on the second screen: **Unlock it** by swiping the padlock to the right

Comment: Works now, thanks!  Though it seems I have to launch twice -- the first time I can start the emulator; the second time, I actually get the app.

Comment: Also, check out http://www.genymotion.com/. The default emulator is VERY slow. Genymotion is much quicker :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can plug an android device into your computer and debug the application on that. It's a lot faster, plus it stays on the device.